# Inferred generic return type accepts object with unknown properties

Tags: typescript, inferred-type

Consider the following:

```js
function returnObject<T>(input: T, processor: (input: T) => T): T {
  return processor(input);
}

type MyObject = {
  foo: number;
};

const myObject: MyObject = { foo: 0 };

const processedObject: MyObject = returnObject(myObject, (input) => ({
  ...input,
  bar: 1,
}));

console.log(processedObject);
```

This builds and runs, outputting:

`{ foo: 0, bar: 1 }`

The problem I have with this is that it should not build. The second argument to `returnObject` is adding the `bar` property to the result, which I would expect to throw a type error as `bar` is not a property of `MyObject`. Indeed, inspecting the type of `processedObject` in tsserver, yields `MyObject` - so it seems like Typescript has actually been fooled into thinking it is a valid `MyObject` based on the inferred type (the behaviour is the same with and without the explicit `: MyObject` after `const processedObject`).

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Typescript, but it doesn't seem like expected behaviour to me?

Comment: It *is* a valid `MyObject`. It has every property required for it to be a valid `MyObject`. Your question seems to be based on a simple misunderstanding of what types in Typescript mean.

Comment: @kaya3 In that case, why does this throw a type error:

`type MyObject = { foo: number; } const myObject: MyObject = { foo: 0, bar: 1 }`

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem very intuitive to me though. Surely a type is a type, regardless of if it's inferred or declared.

Comment: That's a different thing - "excess property checking for object literals". It's not strictly speaking a type error, it's more like the compiler telling you that some code you wrote is probably a mistake (even though it is type-safe).

Comment: That's interesting, I don't think I've heard of that as a concept in other languages. In C, if you try to add an unknown property to a `struct`, it throws a type error.

Comment: In C it has to be a type error, because C would not allocate the extra memory for an extra property in a struct. In Javascript (and hence also Typescript), extra properties can be dynamically added to objects because they're pretty much just hashtables under the hood. Think about Typescript types more like interfaces - they specify what properties the object needs to have, but a class implementing an interface can have more than just what the interface requires.